# Reads per write is high, but why does DMV ask to remove the index?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2008

What could be the reason that a DMV asks to remove an index when the reads per write is 200%? It makes sense to remove those indexes that has less number of reads compared to writes. Are there best practices followed to determine if a index can be removed or should be retained based on reads per writes?

Comment: What DMV are you looking at that says to remove the index?  The only thing that I can think of that would come close is sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats, but that gives you just raw data, not recommendations...

Comment: reads/write of 200% doesn't sound particularly good to me. Doesn't that mean that there are only 2 reads for every write?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something to consider is the counts in those index usage DMVs are **transactions** not **rows**.

For all you know you could be using the index to read 100 rows and then updating 100,000,000 rows with another transaction.  Both of these would report as `1` for the read/write count.